Determine whether arc is collinear within a tolerance
Scanning the internet, there are roughly 2 commonly used algorithms to determine whether an arc is collinear within a tolerance. One with slopes and one with areas. Notice: to be sure: with tolerance I mean: the midpoint of the arc has a distance (within the tolerance) to the line from start and end coordinates of the arc.
Collinear definition - three points defining the arc are collinear, meaning they lie on a straight line rather than forming a curve. For Spatial GIS databases, that is often not allowed.
The used algoritms are not correct when the middle point is not exactly in the middle between the start and end coordinates of the arc.
A good way of determining whether an arc is collinear is to actually calculate the center of the circle through the 3 coordinates, then determining the midpoint of the arc and then calculating the distance between that midpoint and the line (from start to end coordinates). OK, that works, but is not a cheap operation.
What is the best and cheapest way to determine whether the arc is collinear within a tolerance? Is there a better algorithm than the one above? I hope the algorithm looks like Java ;-)
